# Cannot show/hide div when hover on link using display:block

Tags: jquery, css, hide, layer

I am trying to show hide div blocks depending on the link on which it hovers. I have main category and sub-categories. I would like show the sub-category (of the relevant main category) only when someone hovers on maincategory.I tried the following but dont seem to work. 
All helps are appreciated.

### Code

```
      <style type="text/css">
      <!--
      .series-wrapper
      { display:none;}


      .brandcat li a:hover .series-wrapper 
       { display:block;}
      -->
      </style>    


    <div class="brandcat">
    <h3>Most Popular Brands</h3>
    <ul class="brands">
    <li><a href='showbrand.php?bd_id=1'>Apple</a>
        <div class='series-wrapper'><h5>Select your Apple Series</h5>
            <a href='showseries.php?s_id=1'>Apple Mainseries1</a>
            <a href='showseries.php?s_id=3'>Test2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href='showbrand.php?bd_id=2'>Ball</a>
        <div class='series-wrapper'><h5>Select your Ball Series</h5>
            <a href='showseries.php?s_id=1'>Ball Mainseries1</a>
            <a href='showseries.php?s_id=3'>Ball Test2</a>
        </div>
    </li>

          </ul>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **.series-wrapper** is not a descentor of **anchor**.It's with **anchor** . Write like this

```
.brandcat li a:hover + .series-wrapper { display:block;}
```

Comment: fabulous. Thanks a lot..I was trying to solve since last few hours but got mad!

Comment: It worked very nicely. Onlyone more thing if you can help, how can I bring the div series-wrapper box beside the main category link...I have given the box style to div .series wrapper but it shows at the top middle part of the page

Comment: Forget the last part..made it work by positioning the div. Thanks.

Comment: 1 Problem though - when I try to go to the div of subcategory that is move my mouse out of the maincategory the sub category block again hides away making it impossible to select anything from that block :(

Comment: Write like this .brandcat li:hover .series-wrapper { display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix but not reliable:

```
.brandcat li:hover .series-wrapper {
    display:block;
}
```

Correct fix:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.brandcat .series-wrapper {
    display:none;
}

.brandcat li:hover .series-wrapper,
.brandcat li.active .series-wrapper {
    display:block;
}
-->
</style>
```

BODY:

```
<div class="brandcat">
  <h3>Most Popular Brands</h3>
  <ul class="brands">
    <li><a href='showbrand.php?bd_id=1'>Apple</a>
      <div class='series-wrapper'>
        <h5>Select your Apple Series</h5>
        <a href='showseries.php?s_id=1'>Apple Mainseries1</a> <a href='showseries.php?s_id=3'>Test2</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href='showbrand.php?bd_id=2'>Ball</a>
      <div class='series-wrapper'>
        <h5>Select your Ball Series</h5>
        <a href='showseries.php?s_id=1'>Ball Mainseries1</a> <a href='showseries.php?s_id=3'>Ball Test2</a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.brands > li').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```